# How to generate ALL floating numbers?

Tags: c++, floating-point, numeric

I'm trying to generate ALL float numbers to a file on C++ (using gcc). My first attempt was to use `FLT_MIN`, `FLT_MAX` & `FLT_EPSILON` to generate them, the code was something like this:

```
#include <cfloat>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    FILE* handle = freopen("todos_los_float.in","w",stdout);
    for(float x = FLT_MIN; x < FLT_MAX; x = x + FLT_EPSILON)
        cout << x << endl;
    fclose(handle);
    return 0;
}
```

This is not working, as FLT_EPSILON destroys the precision of the number, for `FLT_MIN` it takes a huge jump, and it's stop adding much before reaching `FLT_MAX`.

I have thought on working and adding on binary form, and just skip the special meanings (inf, -inf, NaN) but I'm also not sure which is the best approach for this. How do you suggest to generate the numbers?

Comment: You do realize that will generate a file 40-80GB in size, correct?

Comment: You might find [Bruce Dawson's articles](http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/02/07/float-precision-revisited-nine-digit-float-portability/) useful; it includes examples that iterate over all float (single precision) values.

Comment: Every 32 bit pattern that does not have the exponent field all-ones represents a finite number number.

Comment: Regarding the file size... Yes, it's mainly curiosity, but I'm still going to use the iteration for some real tests on numeric analysis (on smaller ranges).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even barring the other problems, your loop only generates the positive floats. The smallest float is `-inf`, and the smallest finite float is `-FLT_MAX`.

Anyway, if you are trying to generate all the positive finite floats, this should do:

```
#include <cfloat>
#include <cmath>
...
float f;
for (f=0.0f; f<INFINITY; f = nextafterf(f, INFINITY)) …
```

Note that the smallest float above 0.0 is not `FLT_MIN`, it is `FLT_MIN * FLT_EPSILON`.
It would also have worked to set the FPU rounding mode to round-upward and to add `FLT_MIN * FLT_EPSILON` until +inf was reached.

Comment: Thanks! this is really useful. I'm indeed only interested on positive numbers, so this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Study [IEEE floating point format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision_floating-point_format). Then simply generate all distinct bit patterns that represent finite values (skip all `INF`s and `NaN`s).

Comment: (a) This does not work for all floating-point implementations, whereas `nextafter` is portable. (b) This answer states to generate bit patterns, but the question asks for floating-point numbers. So it is missing the step of converting bit patterns to floating-point numbers, which is tricky to do without violating language rules.

Answer (score 2):

There's `std::nextafter`:

```
for (float f = 0; f != FLT_MAX; f = std::nextafter(f, FLT_MAX)) { }
```

Comment: It is a detail, but the body of your loop is not executed for `f == FLT_MAX`.